# SupportMapFragment Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, google-maps-android-api-2

Tell me, why does not work?
Gives every second.
And shows a blank cell.

[image]

With the settings "AndroidManifest" should be all right, because a few hours before work.

```
ActivityThread Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices
```

A few hours ago, everything worked, no change is made.

```
public class TravelMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GPSTrackerService gpsService;

    private SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.travel_map_activity);

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

//This option does not work either.

//      mMapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
//      try {
//          MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
//      } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
//          // TODO handle error
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
//      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, mMapFragment).commit();

    }
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the manifest file?

Comment: Yes, I solved this problem.